# Python regex probelm

Tags: python, regex, pandas, pyspark

I am trying to convert
pandas dtypes ==> pyspark schema.

ie.
Convert following text

```
PERSONID      int64
LASTNAME     object
FIRSTNAME    object
ADDRESS      object
CITY         object
RESULT         bool
```

Into

```
StructField('PERSONID',IntegerType(),True),
StructField('LASTNAME',StringType(),True),
StructField('FIRSTNAME',StringType(),True),
StructField('ADDRESS',StringType(),True),
StructField('CITY',StringType(),True),
StructField('RESULT',BooleanType(),True)
```

So far I have done this:

```py
import re

query = """
PERSONID      int64
LASTNAME     object
FIRSTNAME    object
ADDRESS      object
CITY         object
RESULT         bool
""";

mapping = {'int64': 'IntegerType()',
           'float64': 'DoubleType',
           'bool': 'BooleanType()',
           'object': 'StringType()'
          }


regexp = '(\w+)\s+(\w+)'

re.match(query,regexp)
```

I am new to regex syntaxes.

How to achieve the required result?

Comment: If the structure is consistent, using the string.strip() method might work better

Comment: I am trying to learn Regex here.

Comment: May I suggest mentioning it in your original post next time?
But your regex actually works according to regex101 (although it is quite slow). So could you clarify what exactly you are struggling with?

Comment: I need the output as shown in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem without using regexp. Regular expressions are often not the most readable solution. Especially after some time of not using them or when the expression is a 50-character string. Pure language syntax will always be clearer and there is less chance that you will forget it.

## Syntax solution:

I have divided solution into parts, so you can study it part by part.

```
query_s = query.rstrip().lstrip()
query_s = query_s.split(sep='\n')
query_s = [ x.split() for x in query_s ]
query_s = [ [x[0], mapping[x[1]]] for x in query_s ]
query_s = [ [ "StructField(\'", x[0], "\',", x[1], ",True)," ] for x in query_s ]
query_s = [ ''.join(x) for x in query_s ]
```

## Regex solution:

```
query_s = query.split(sep='\n')
query_s = [x for x in query_s if x]
query_s = [ ["StructField(\'", re.match(r"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)", x).group(1), "\',", mapping[re.match(r"^(\w+)\s+(\w+)", x).group(2)], ",True)"] for x in query_s ]
out = [''.join(x) for x in query_s]
```

You can pass a callable to `re.sub`, so to make it prettier you can write some nice function to treat matches and pass it to `re.sub()`

Comment: After posting an answer I see that you have commented about the necessity of regex use. As Sam wrote, please mention it in your original post next time.

Comment: Nevermind, even though I need regex, I will award with upvote. Congrats on first 10 points.